# Is matching necessary for prediction from logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, matching

I have a data set with very imbalanced groups (about 3% have an effect, while 97% don't).
I experimented with logistic regression and was convinced that I can get to a very good accuracy of prediction without matching.

In which cases is matching necessary, then?

Comment: Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283170/when-is-unbalanced-data-really-a-problem-in-machine-learning

Comment: Accuracy is probably one of the least convincing classification metrics when we are dealing with unbalanaced data.