# Is it normal for ROC curve thresholds to be Inf or -Inf?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, roc

I am running a binary classification with a random forest via the `ranger` package in `R`, and am using the `pROC` package for building an ROC curve and calculating AUC. But, the using the `coords()` function returns only three rows, and two of them are either `-Inf` or `Inf`.

```
> coords(rf_roc)
  threshold specificity sensitivity
1      -Inf       0.000       1.000
2       0.5       0.692       0.806
3       Inf       1.000       0.000
```

My question is: Is this normal, or does it indicate that there is an issue in my model/data?

For reference, I've included the confusion matrix results:

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction   0   1
         0 211  72
         1  94 300
                                             
               Accuracy : 0.755              
                 95% CI : (0.721, 0.787)     
    No Information Rate : 0.549              
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : <0.0000000000000002
                                             
                  Kappa : 0.502              
                                             
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.103              
                                             
            Sensitivity : 0.806              
            Specificity : 0.692              
         Pos Pred Value : 0.761              
         Neg Pred Value : 0.746              
             Prevalence : 0.549              
         Detection Rate : 0.443              
   Detection Prevalence : 0.582              
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.749              
                                             
       'Positive' Class : 1
```

Comment: It is a tad unusual, because realistically if we are using a probit or logit link function as most methods implementing probabilistic classifiers do, $\geq 0$ should suffice but to play it safe using $\infty$ is OK too. ROC is not defined only for classifiers afterall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes sense. The only way to be assured of always getting perfect sensitivity is to classify everything as the positive class, which is equivalent to classifying as positive if the predicted value exceeds $-\infty$. Likewise, the only way to get perfect specificity is to classify everything as the negative class, which is equivalent to classifying as negative if the predicted value is below $+\infty$. While you might be able to get perfect sensitivity by setting the threshold just below the lowest prediction or perfect specificity by setting the threshold just above the highest prediction, that only applies to your particular data and, in general, cannot be assured of giving perfect sensitivity or specificity. Thus, it makes sense that the developers would hard-code the $\pm\infty$ in the `coords` function, as those are the only thresholds that will assure perfect sensitivity or specificity (granted, at the expense of each other).

I even got the `Inf` for some simulated data. That there is perfect sensitivity and specificity for finite thresholds is addressed below in **EDIT 2**.

```
set.seed(2023)
N <- 20
p <- rbeta(N, 1/2, 1/2) # simulated probability predictions
y <- rbinom(N, 1, p)    # simulated true classes
r <- pROC::roc(y, p)
coords(r)

################################################################################

> coords(r)
    threshold specificity sensitivity
1        -Inf         0.0         1.0
2  0.02950050         0.1         1.0
3  0.04154948         0.2         1.0
4  0.07094372         0.3         1.0
5  0.09818741         0.4         1.0
6  0.11496482         0.5         1.0
7  0.13298654         0.6         1.0
8  0.16426112         0.7         1.0
9  0.22426518         0.8         1.0
10 0.41298569         0.8         0.9
11 0.60549653         0.8         0.8
12 0.68211752         0.8         0.7
13 0.75138334         0.8         0.6
14 0.78644297         0.8         0.5
15 0.79864440         0.8         0.4
16 0.81317781         0.8         0.3
17 0.84750176         0.9         0.3
18 0.88146272         1.0         0.3
19 0.92519032         1.0         0.2
20 0.98128671         1.0         0.1
21        Inf         1.0         0.0
```

**EDIT**

The comments correctly point out that you can get perfect sensitivity or specificity in the above example without going to infinite thresholds. This is because my example simulates probability predictions from a model. However, the `roc` function can handle any continuum of values, such as log-odds.

```
set.seed(2023)
N <- 20
p <- rbeta(N, 1/2, 1/2) # simulated probability predictions
y <- rbinom(N, 1, p)    # simulated true classes
r <- pROC::roc(y, log(p/(1-p)))
pROC::coords(r)
```

As the probabilities get very small or very large, the log-odds approach $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, respectively.

**EDIT 2**

The reason there are perfect sensitivity and specificity values in the R output is because the simulation happens not to give $1$ for any of the very low `p` values and not to give $0$ for any of the high values for the very high `p` values. In theory, though, for any probability in $(0,1)$ (or any real value of the log-odds), any point can have any true category, no matter how remote the chance of that happening, necessitating the $\pm\infty$ thresholds as the only ways of assuring perfect sensitivity (catch all $1$s, no matter how many $0$s are misclassified) or perfect specificity (catch all $0$, no matter how many $1$s are misclassified).

Comment: "The only way to get perfect sensitivity is to classify everything as the positive class"  That isn't true, and your example shows it.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that for most probabilistic classifiers who already use probit/logit link functions, using $[0, 1]$ would be fine too. The issue is that we can define ROC for any continuous metric.

Comment: @BenReiniger I wonder where exactly you see such a counterexample in the ROC shown in Dave's example. You realize classifying each observation as a positive equates to setting the threshold to $- \infty$ correct?

Comment: @BenReiniger I have made some edits in light of your insightful comment.

Comment: @AdamO e.g. at 0.2 the sensitivity is still 1.  Dave has addressed that in the second edit section, plus the addition of the phrase "assured of" at the beginning.

Comment: @BenReiniger ah the classic confusion of "for this particular problem" vs "for any particular problem".

Comment: Thank you for your edits. +1