# Random sampling for both under- and over-representative class

Tags: unbalanced-classes

I have an unbalanced dataset. Let's say I have 500 positives and 50,000 negatives. Can I deal with this by randomly choose 300 out of 500 positives and also 300 out of 50,000 negatives? Does this suffer from the problem of *implicitly* choosing Ys that have different Xs, which is described in this article: https://gking.harvard.edu/files/0s.pdf

Comment: Please tell us why you think unbalanced classes is a problem, and read https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283170/when-is-unbalanced-data-really-a-problem-in-machine-learning

Comment: My problem is that I have 70% accuracy for the minority but only 50% accuracy for the majority. Which means that overall I expect to make 500*0.7 + 49,500*0.5 = 25,100 correct predictions out of 50,000 predictions, which seems random. I'm trying to fix this somehow by subsampling.