# Why is importance-weighted empirical risk minimization finite-sample biased?

Tags: regression, sample, unbalanced-classes, weighted-regression, covariate-shift

Classical risk minimization (RM) minimizes the expected loss over the *training* distribution $p_{\mathrm{train}}(x)$,

$$\theta^*_{RM} = \arg \min_\theta E[\ell(x, \theta)]_{p_{\text{train}}}.$$

As the distribution $p_{\text{train}}$ is usually unknown, empirical risk minimization (ERM) replaces the analytical expectation with the sample expectation, i.e.,

$$\theta^*_{ERM} = \arg \min_\theta \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \ell(x_i, \theta).$$

Now suppose the training data are drawn from a distribution $p_{\mathrm{train}}(x)$, but you would like the model to perform well on data drawn from another distribution $p_{\mathrm{target}}(x)$. This is what's called "covariate shift", and in this case, we would like to minimize the expected loss over the *target* distribution, giving rise to *importance-weighted risk minimization* (IWRM)

$$ \theta^*_{IWRM} = \arg \min_\theta E[\ell(x, \theta)]_{p_{\text{target}}} \\ 
= \arg \min_\theta E\left[\frac{p_{\text{target}}(x)}{p_{\text{train}}(x)}\ell(x, \theta)\right]_{p_{\text{train}}} $$

and its finite-sample counterpart, *importance-weighted empirical risk minimization* (IWERM):

$$\theta^*_{IWERM}= \arg \min_\theta \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \underbrace{\frac{p_{\text{target}}(x_i)}{p_{\text{train}}(x_i)}}_{=w_i} \ell(x_i, \theta).$$

In practice, this amounts to simply weighting individual samples by their importance $w_i$.

[Shimodaira (2000)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378375800001154) proves that (assuming $p_{\text{train}}$ and $p_{\text{target}}$ to be known) the IWERM estimator is asymptotically unbiased, i.e., for $N\to\infty$ we have

$$\theta^*_{IWERM} = \arg \min_\theta E[\ell(x, \theta)]_{p_{\text{target}}}.$$

My question is: **why does this not hold for finite sample numbers as well?** I would think that the estimator should also be unbiased for finite $N$, but that does not appear to be the case. Can someone explain why?

Here's an example demonstrating the biasedness of IWERM estimation for $N<\infty$. $N=500$ samples $x_i$ are drawn from a Gamma distribution, truncated to [0,10] ($p_{\text{train}}$), and $p_{\text{target}}$ is the uniform distribution over the same interval. A line is fit to a 4th-order polynomial $f(x)$ (with additive Gaussian noise of constant variance), and the cost function is the squared error. The figure shows one realization of the data; the regression lines are averaged over 1000 realizations. OLS = (unweighted) ordinary least squares, IWLS = importance-weighted least squares, ideal = solution that minimizes the expected squared error over $p_{\text{train}}$, the uniform distribution. For larger values of $N$, the IWLS solution converges to the "ideal" solution, in accordance with the asymptotic unbiasedness shown by Shimodaira.

[image]

(The intro to this question is adapted from [my answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/475176/131402).)

The full R code to reproduce the above figure can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/Z319gFqi).

Answer (score 1):

The importance-weighted empirical risk *is* an unbiased estimator for the risk with respect to the target distribution, for any N.

But it's difficult to say anything about the *minimizer* of the importance-weighted empirical risk for finite sample sizes.

Let's abstract this a bit:

- Let F be a functional (i.e. takes in a function f and returns a number).
- Let G be random functional such that E[G(f)] = F(f) for every function f.
- In the IWERM scenario, F(f) is the expected error of f with respect to the target distribution, and G(f) is the importance weighted empirical error of f on the training sample.
- You're basically asking whether we have: E[ argmin_f G(f) ] = argmin_f F(f), where f ranges over some set of functions (in your example, affine functions).  I don't see any reason for this to be true.

One reason you would expect this to be false in the machine learning setting is overfitting.  If we don't have a lot of data and we're fitting using a very expressive space of functions (e.g. neural networks or high degree polynomials), we may fit the data very well but perform terribly on new data.  This will happen whether or not we're importance sampling.  (I don't think this is what's happening in your simulation.)

Here's the paper I originally referenced, just for the record. "[Learning Bounds for Importance Weighting](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2010/file/59c33016884a62116be975a9bb8257e3-Paper.pdf)" by Cortes et al.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and sorry for the super late reply! Only now found the time to check that paper and think about the topic again. I'm not sure I follow yet, though. Does the paper say anything about finite-sample importance weighted estimation being _biased_? I thought it only claimed that it is not _efficient_?

Comment: Just to emphasize again, the IWLS line in my graph is not a single realization of the IWLS result; instead, it is averaged over 1000 realizations and shows a clear bias. The papers I found so far all seem to imply that IWLS is unbiased in finite samples as well (although not efficient), but I could not find a clear statement of that.

Comment: I also just added a link to the R code for my example, if that's of any use. I'm really quite confused as to what's going on.

Comment: Code looks reasonable to me -- I added some more comments to my answer.

Comment: Can you share the references? "The papers I found so far all seem to imply that IWLS is unbiased in finite samples as well"