# Learning Distribution of Data

Tags: data-augmentation, synthetic-data

Sometimes it's important to generate data due to data imbalance issues. I heard that data augmentation by leaning distribution of data is a hot topic now. Could you please give me some resources and useful material for data generation by learning data distribution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is unbalanced data really a problem in Machine Learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283170/when-is-unbalanced-data-really-a-problem-in-machine-learning). In particular, see [this recent answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/475176/28500) to the question.