# Oversampling/undersampling issue

Tags: logistic, mathematical-statistics, sampling, predictive-models, inference

Assume original data contains 1000 goods and 1 bad
I build a logistic regression and use the the model to score the bad and I get probability = 0.00001
Then I use oversampling/undersampling to increase/decrease the original data so now I have 1000 goods and 1000 bags if I use oversampling.
Then I build a logistic model use the data and apply the model to the original data then for that bad I get probability = 0.5.
However this probability need to be adjusted to reflect original data so  after doing some math you get adjusted probability lower than 0.5 (for example 0.00001 ) so what is the point of oversampling/undersampling if you are required to adjust the probability?

Comment: The point of oversampling is unclear to many. See the discussion in the comments to [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352)

Comment: Still don’t understand

Comment: It would help to explain what it is you do not understand.

Comment: My  question is asking why do you need to adjust probability after

Comment: I think @StephanKolassa will agree with me that you do not need to do that, because you should not be oversampling or undersampling in the first place. I find it hard to argue for a correct conclusion to a wrong procedure.