# Imbalanced data output better than balanced data

Tags: machine-learning, svm, linear

I'm currently doing sentiment anaylisis with SVM algorithm linear kernel and TF-IDF. My data is not balanced

not balanced:

[image: not balanced data]

and I balanced data using SMOTE

balanced data:

[image: balanced data]

output without balanced data:

[image: output without balanced data]

output with balanced data:

[image: output with balanced data]

Why output without balanced data is more better than balanced data?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. I recommend that you have a look at the question [When is unbalanced data really a problem in Machine Learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283170/when-is-unbalanced-data-really-a-problem-in-machine-learning).