# Is weighting still needed when using undersampling?

Tags: sampling, model-evaluation, precision-recall

I have an model that I want to test with my existing data to calculate precision, recall etc.
The data is actually unbalanced dataset: Class A 70%/Class B 30%.
I created a data set by undersampling class A, so that I get an equal distribution of both classes: Class A 50%/Class B 50%.
When calculating the metrics for evaluation, do I have to weight the results? So would a false positive have a higher weight, due to the unbalance in the actual population?

Comment: In short, your metrics are not appropriate for your data, change the metrics not the data.

Comment: Please take some time to read what's already written about these topics on Cross Validated. Good places to start: [When is unbalanced data really a problem in Machine Learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/283170/237901) and [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/237901).